# Processor serial number

Tags: c++

I need PSN of CPU.
I write code like

```
int info[4] = { -1 };
__cpuid(info, 1);
int family = info[0] & 0xf00;
int features = info[3] & 0xf000;

std::stringstream psn_id;
```

How i get Processor serial number?
Can anyone please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: As a general rule, you can't. It's usually disable by default by the BIOS of x86 machines. What's your outer problem? Why do you think you need this? (It won't work for the reasons most people tend to want it because it cannot be verified.)

Comment: I need for identifying it unique from other PC.

Comment: Just securely generate a random 128-bit number and store it in a file then. That will uniquely identify the PC. PSN won't work well on systems that have more than one CPU (the PSN can change based on which CPU the code happens to run on) or have the PSN disabled. ALso, it will think you have a different PC if you change the CPU. So PSN is a bad choice for uniquely identifying a PC.

Answer (score 0):

What OS? If Windows then instead of the CPU serial you could uniquely identify the pc using the volume serial number associated with the filesystem using the system call [GetVolumeInformation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
DWORD serial;
::GetVolumeInformation(_T("C:\\"), NULL, 0, &serial, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

Then use `serial` as your unique identifier instead.

Comment: when machine get formatted then serial number remains same or not

Comment: @user1586515 The MSDN link that I've provided in the answer tells you that it won't be the same, and it then gives you an alternative to get the manufacturer's serial number which won't change.

Comment: If you create a disk image and then apply it to a number of machines then they will have the same serial number.  The serial number is a *logical* one rather than a *physical* one.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getPSN(char *PSN)
{int varEAX, varEBX, varECX, varEDX;
   char str[9];
   //%eax=1 gives most significant 32 bits in eax 
   __asm__ __volatile__ ("cpuid": "=a" (varEAX), "=b" (varEBX), "=c" (varECX), "=d" (varEDX) : "a" (1));
   sprintf(str, "%08X", varEAX); //i.e. XXXX-XXXX-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
   sprintf(PSN, "%C%C%C%C-%C%C%C%C", str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5], str[6], str[7]);
   //%eax=3 gives least significant 64 bits in edx and ecx [if PN is enabled]
   __asm__ __volatile__ ("cpuid": "=a" (varEAX), "=b" (varEBX), "=c" (varECX), "=d" (varEDX) : "a" (3));
   sprintf(str, "%08X", varEDX); //i.e. xxxx-xxxx-XXXX-XXXX-xxxx-xxxx
   sprintf(PSN, "%s-%C%C%C%C-%C%C%C%C", PSN, str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5], str[6], str[7]);
   sprintf(str, "%08X", varECX); //i.e. xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-XXXX-XXXX
   sprintf(PSN, "%s-%C%C%C%C-%C%C%C%C", PSN, str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5], str[6], str[7]);
}

int main()
{
    char PSN[30]; //24 Hex digits, 5 '-' separators, and a '\0'
    getPSN(PSN);
    printf("%s\n", PSN); //compare with: lshw | grep serial:
    return 0;
}
```